# How to make upload button submit files without second submit button php Symfony3

Tags: javascript, php, forms, symfony

I have `upload` button. Currently when it is clicked there is a new button `save` showing which submits the form with the data. Is it possible after `upload` is clicked to open a tab in which to select files and after files are selected if `Open` is clicked to submit the form without the need of a second button?
Imagine I have this code

```
<form action="/upload" method="post">
  <input type="file" name="uploadButton" value="Upload Images"/>
</form>
```

Is it possible for this button to submit the form and send the data without second button `save`. I am using Symfony 3.3 and twig templates. I know javascript if it can help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Add an event listener to automatically submit the form when input changes?

Comment: Never thought of it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an event listener to automatically submit the form when input changes:

HTML:

```
<form id="myform" action="/upload" method="post">
  <input id="myinput" type="file" name="uploadButton" value="Upload Images"/>
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
var form = document.getElementById('myform');
var input = document.getElementById('myinput');

var change_running = false;    
input.addEventListener('change', function(){
    if(!change_running){
        setTimeout(function(){
            change_running = true;
            form.submit();
            change_running = false;     
        }, 300);
    }
});
```

Comment: Seemed to work at first, but then when I add more than one file it submits the form with only the first one. I must add that I used the short way in the HTML saw that there is "onChange". The reason being that I need this for many buttons related to different galeries at the same page (in one table) and each form having different ID and "onChange" worked fine, until I tried uploading multiple files. For some reason this way it submits the form before having all files but the first one

Comment: a more detailed code would be nice. anyway, you can try to addEventListener on the last input you have.

Comment: That's some interesting behaviour. I don't really like the idea, but you could add a delay to the onchange event. I added some code to my answer. The boolean is just to make sure, that the form isn't submitted more than once. I'm not sure if multiple files trigger the change event more than once.

Comment: I've just tested what the input contains...if I select 3 files it console.logs out all 3 files. https://jsfiddle.net/ykv3rL3x/ I don't know why it would only submit one. Do you have your form set to multipart?